# How to disable .vspscc file being checkedout whenever i open a VS 2010 solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration

Whenever i open my VS 2010 project i find .vspscc file being checkedout at the same level as my .sln file is checkout from TFS. How to disable .vspscc file being checkedout whenever i open a VS 2010 solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 you can use `TF Distroy` command utility in order to delete from source control

2 you can also use right-click on files  and choose `"Delete"` on `Source Control.`

Comment: does deleting.vspscc file permanently causes any issues with the binding with tfs server?!

Comment: right it's bad he can create problem, but i answer to your question if uou want disable file,,

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be to exclude it from the source control. [Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/tfsgeneral/thread/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4) a more details explanation  what this file is needed for

Comment: So your saying you should exclude the files from source control that contain the information about which files are excluded from source control? Wouldn't this create some earth shattering feedback loop?

Comment: No it will not. The file must stay in your file system. Only detached from tfs. In other words, not monitored by TFS, but used each time You open pending changes dialog

Comment: Fair enough, but this will have an impact on other developers changing the same project. They will also need to exclude the file otherwise a new one could get generated and checked in

Comment: Well, there's always and option of starting to use one of the DCVS`es like Mercurial (tortoiseHG) or Git ;)

Comment: A TFS developer posted [this](https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/tag/team-foundation-server/), stating that .VSPSCC and .VSSSCC files should not be added to TFS.